# Automate backups rsync + snapshot and archives rotation

Tags: server, backup, rsync, rsnapshot

I'm looking for a command line solution to automate backups of system files from my server Ubuntu installation with Rsync and take snapshots of them to a remote location (home NAS).

Ideally with a rotation of compressed and time-stamped backups.

Previously I manually backed up my system once a month but it happens to be forgotten, so I need to keep my backups up to date.

I know Timeshift which is perfect but I can't find anything to use it from the command line.

Anyone have a solution to offer me?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I use LuckyBackup which is available from the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

This utility can be used from the command line and provides an easy interface to rsync with the opportunity to schedule backups.

Just as importantly, it allows you to perform a dummy run to check your configuration and to fine-tune your options.

[Overview](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/easy-linux-backups-lucky-backup/)

[User Manual](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/manual.html)